# How can i save my XAML content into a File?

Tags: silverlight

I have a problem. I want to save a XAML state into a file, or something like this. I developed a Silverlight version of PowerPoint, and now i want to save my presentation, but i don't know how...i'm using Silverlight 3 beta(if helps)...

I would like to allow users to upload their photos, music and video file somewhere.....where and how can i do this?

Thanks,
Andrei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by saving data in XML files. When i want to recreate the state of the app i set all the parameters from my XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a toughy.  WPF has the Xaml Writer which can send that state out.  Silverlight doesn't :(

What you're doing sounds a lot like [Mike Harsh's Silverlight 3 sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/mharsh/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-beta-sample-slidentity-presentation-creation-app.aspx).  His source is available;  Maybe that will provide a suitable approach.

Comment: I know that sample. But it dosen't help me. Thank you.